# UVs not connecting when adding texture

Tags: texturing, uv, normals

First time posting here. Not sure what's going on with my model, but when unwrapping UVs I noticed the normals are somehow not touching? There are no modifiers or anything else applied to this model currently. I'm not sure how best to describe it. See attached screenshot. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You mean you obtain that just by UV unwrapping?

Comment: After playing around with it, this is more so with just applying the material. The issue is the material is applied to other objects without any issues, so I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: transparency in this material?

Comment: You should either share the blend file or copy a screen capture with the uvs over the texture

Comment: I figured it out... The displacement in the material was causing the issue. I unplugged it and the material looks normal again. Thanks!